# While trying to creating posts on Hashnode using their GraphQL APIs while using python's requests library gives errors

Tags: api, python-requests, graphql

This is the function I have been using create a post in Hashnode via there GraphQL APIs referring this blog [Introducing Hashnode GraphQL API - Public Beta](https://engineering.hashnode.com/introducing-hashnode-graphql-api-public-beta-cjydzvp59001q2gs1b5zxaeaf)

```
def post_to_hashnode():
    URL = "https://api.hashnode.com"
    headers = {
        'Authorization':HASHNODE_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    query = """{
        mutation {
             createStory(
                input: {
                    title: "The hashnode GraphQL API is here"
                    contentMarkdown: "<h1> Ahoy </h1>"
                    tags: [
                        {
                            _id: "56744721958ef13879b94c7e"
                            name: "General Programming"
                            slug: "programming"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ) {
                message
                post{
                    title
                }
            }
        }
    }
    """
    response = requests.post(URL, json={'query':query}, headers=headers)
    return response.text
```

And the error it throws out is

> {"errors":[{"message":"Cannot query field "mutation" on type "Query".","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED"}}]}

Tried another way of querying after looking at some more examples in the blog

```
def post_to_hashnode():
    URL = "https://api.hashnode.com"
    headers = {
        'Authorization':HASHNODE_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    body = json.dumps({
            "query": "mutation createStory($input: CreateStoryInput!){ createStory(input: $input){ title } }",
            "variables": {
            "input": {
                "title": "What are the e2e testing libraries you use ?",
                "contentMarkdown": "I was wondering what e2e testing libaries do you use",
                "tags": [
                {
                    "_id": "56744723958ef13879b9549b",
                    "slug": "testing",
                    "name": "Testing"
                }
                ],
                "coverImage": "https://cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image-dev/upload/v1562665620141/tc-h-erqF.jpeg",
            }
            }
        })
    response = requests.post(URL, data=body, headers=headers)
    return response.text
```

which still results in a different error though

> {"errors":[{"message":"Cannot query field "title" on type "CreatePostOutput".","locations":[{"line":1,"column":78}],"extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED"}}]}

Comment: tested on graphiql/playground? ... "We are just getting started. So, feel free to share any bugs, feedback or your cool ideas in our Discord server."

Comment: @xadm Yes I have tested this on playground, it works fine there. It should be some problem with the way I am sending this request.

Sure, I will share this in the discord server

Comment: try to ignore/omit 'mutation' word ... or declare `$input` arguments (you should, test using 'query variables' in playground) and 'operation name' ... use search/google for better code examples

Comment: bad query return structure ... you forgot that `title` is inside `post`

Answer (score 0):

You are right, need to rearrange a little bit.

```
import requests

def post_to_hashnode():
    URL = "https://api.hashnode.com"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "YOUR_KEY_HERE",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    query = """
            mutation createStory($input: CreateStoryInput!) {
                createStory(input: $input) {
                    code
                    success
                    message
                }
            }
    """
    
    response = requests.post(URL, json={
        "query": query,
        "variables": {
            "input": {
                "title": "Test posts here",
                "contentMarkdown": "<h1> Ahoy </h1>",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "_id": "56744721958ef13879b94c7e",
                        "name": "General Programming",
                        "slug": "programming"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, headers=headers)
    return response.text

test = post_to_hashnode()
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

"coverImage": "https://cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image-dev/upload/v1562665620141/tc-h-erqF.jpeg",

needs to be replaced with

"coverImageURL": "https://cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image-dev/upload/v1562665620141/tc-h-erqF.jpeg",